# titanium studio adding rows to section

Tags: titanium, tableview, rows

I cannot see what I am doing wrong here. Simply put, I want to add custom row to a section, add the section to a table view, then display the view in my window. Sounds easy enough. I've stepped through my code so many times that I can no longer see what I'm missing (I think we've all been there). So I need a fresh set of eyes to look at it.

First, I know I get data into the row. I add the row to the section via a for loop in the success callback from the server. I get no errors. The section appears in the window. But I simply cannot get the rows to display.

To avoid dumping the code in this block, you can find it pasted [here](http://pastie.org/2555054).

If you need more information, please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: You are creating  var section = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection();
again in your for loop and not adding it to tableView.

Comment: @muhammad I added rowData[] outside the server function and modified the section.add to look like this:                var section = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection();
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                section.add(createRow(results[i].deceased), i);
            }
            rowData.push(section);    That didn't work either. I'm still looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow,
This was a tough nut to crack. One of my more-informed colleagues solved it over the weekend.
Rather than pushing and adding elements to the parent. He simply used the appendRow method to add a row to an empty array which then was added to the table view.

Create the table view first:

```
// CREATE RESULTS TABLEVIEW
var tvResults = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor : "white",
    data : [],
    top : 55,
    left : 10,
    width : 260,
    height : 250,
    borderColor : appHeaderColor,
    borderWidth : 1,
    borderRadius : 10
});
viewMain.add(tvResults);
```

Then in the callback, iterate and append to the array which is added to the view:

```
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {   
   tvResults.appendRow(createRow(results[i].deceased));
}
```

Note that the important piece is **data : [],** in the tableview; the empty array for the data property. Hope this helps someone avoid the headache this caused me.

Comment: what about `var data = []; for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {   
   data.push(createRow(results[i].deceased));
} tvResults.setData(data);`

Answer (score 0):

this should work too

```
var sections = [];
sections[0] = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection;

for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {   
   sections[0].add(createRow(results[i].deceased));
};

var tvResults = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor : "white",
    data : sections
});
viewMain.add(tvResults);
```